# TextInput cursor move to the beginning on reveal/hide password

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having a problem with TextInput cursor when reveal or hide password value, when the user touch the reveal password button the cursor move to the beginning on Android, iOS works as expected.

This is the function of reveal password:

```
displayPass(){
    this.setState({
        hiddenPass: !this.state.hiddenPass
    });
}
```

And this is the TextInput

```
<TextInput onChangeText = {(pass) => this.setState({pass})} 
  secureTextEntry = {this.state.hiddenPass} />
```

And this is the button:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.displayPass.bind(this)}>
    <Text style = {styles.textReveal}>{this.state.hiddenPass ? "Reveal Password" : "Hide Password"}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @RocíoGarcíaLuque I think that issue is still on the RN core, so what I did instead was install this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hide-show-password-input) to handle that

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my comment @GeekDev... this issue was really time-consuming. Yesterday after going mad I finally tested it with Expo 33 and it is working, I'll post an answer with both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DISCLAIMER: For me, it was impossible to fix this under Expo 32. Playing with cursor position, focus/blur and `setNativeProps` did not solve it.

If you need a password input with hide&reveal functionality, your best options are:

- Add `react-native-hide-show-password-input` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hide-show-password-input
- Update **expo to version 33**. You can follow this instructions: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c (you will find the exact lists of dependencies to be updated and their compatible versions).
  After the upgrade, no extra logic will be needed, just use the `TextInput` component. After clicking the "show/hide password" icon, you will see that the cursor stays in the correct position.

Comment: Awesome! I fixed with that first option, the `react-native-hide-show-password-input` I'm going to mark this as solution!